# Unable to get rows to return when trying to select certain value from dataset

Tags: python

i have a very large dataset (its called nyc) that has "fiscal year" as a column. I'm trying to select all rows where the fiscal year is 2021. When I use the value counts function to see how many should have 2021 it should be 573477. I tried the following code:

```
n21 = nyc.loc[nyc['Fiscal Year'] == '2021]
```

but when I print out 21 it doesn't return any rows, just the columns. I've also tried:

```
n21 = nyc[nyc['Fiscal Year'] == '2021]
```

this returns a boolean list which i think could lead me in the right place but i'm not really sure where to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in that case you just put only one "'" on the code, maybe could be the reason you didn't get any data.

if is a string column, you can try

```
n21 = nyc[nyc['Fiscal Year'] == '2021']
```

or in case your column has int64 values

```
n21 = nyc[nyc['Fiscal Year'] == 2021]
```

Comment: i had the ', i tried to remove the '' around 2021 and that worked. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Always be careful with the quotes because they can screw the code xD

Comment: Please, don't forgot to accept my asnwer to "close" this question and help other people :)